# git status, how to ignore some folders

Tags: git, gitignore

My project structure is like this:

```
├── myProject
│   ├── myapp
│   ├── myenv
│   └── db.sqlite3
```

Each time I run:

```
git status
```

I received many status changes of myenv which are not important to me, but the myenv changes are too many, it is very annoying.

I tried to ignore it by creating a .gitignore file:

```
├── myProject
│   ├── myapp
│   ├── myenv
    ├── db.sqlite3
    └── .gitignore
```

Inside it:

```
db.sqlite3
dir_to_ignore/myenv/
```

But it does not work, after running `git status`, still lots of status changes of myenv came out.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means a file in that folder has already been added. The quickest way I find to solve this is to run: `git rm --cache -r dir_to_ignore/myenv/`

Keeping the `dir_to_ignore/myenv/` in your .gitignore. The --cache option simply removes the folder from your git index but not from your filesystem. While still being in the `.gitignore` file means git won't try to add it again.